# How do I temporarily disable Cloudflare Pages deployment?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

I can't delete the active production deployment. I *can* delete the project, and thus lose all my configs. On Google App Engine, I can disable the project. Is there a way to disable Cloudflare Pages?

Edit: To be clear, I meant making it non-accessible. For reference, one reason to do this would be to remove any and all attack surface for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear for me if you want the page to stop being updated but still be accessible or you want it to be unavailable.

### For pages to stop being updated but still being accessible:

Go to your Pages' site and click on the 'Settings' tab.
Next, click on the 'Builds & deployments' section on the left side.

Here you can do several things, depending on why you don't want to publish.
The main idea is to keep published some git branch from the repo which will not be getting any commits.
In the "Configure production deployments" button you have several alternatives, choose the one which makes more sense to you:

- Just uncheck the "Enable automatic production deployments" checkbox.
- Change the published branch on the 'Production' setting to a newly created branch, just for this purpose.
- Stop pushing to the configured 'Production' git branch (usually 'master') and use another branch.

If the purpose why you want to disable is to prevent working changes to get published to production, you might want to use the "Preview deployments" to review and test your development branches. See the docs at: https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/preview-deployments/

### To make the pages not accessible

You can put the page behind a authentication page using an 'Access Policy' in the 'settings' tab to deny everyone but you access. You just have to click 'Enable access policy' and configure it there.
Since it's not clear to me if this is what you're looking for and to keep the answer relevant, I'll not go into detail. If I'm wrong, please clarify what are you trying to accomplish and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to make the page non-accessible. Thanks!